# php warning when use filetime()

Tags: php, html-table

I'm making a table in php that gets the file name in a directory.
Like this:

```
$myDirectory = opendir("./server/sandro/Sandro-PC/Printscreens/");
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}


closedir($myDirectory);


$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

sort($dirArray);
print("<TABLE class=table>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th></TR>\n");

for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ 
        echo('<TR><TD><a href="server/sandro/Sandro-PC/Printscreens/'.$dirArray[$index].'"><img height="80" width="120" src="server/sandro/Sandro-PC/Printscreens/'.$dirArray[$index].'"</a></td>');
        print("<td>");
        echo(filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("<td>");
        print(filesize($dirArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");
```

But in the function `filemtime()` or `filesize()`
give this error:

> Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for image.png in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard3\printscreens.php on line 167

How can I solve this?

Comment: By providing the full filepath

Comment: And reading the example on how to use readdir and how not to use readdir from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code it is fetching the file name but not getting the file path. When we are doing the filesize() or filemtime() please pass the file name with directory. I just modifies the code as below , please try

```
<?php

 $myDirectory = opendir("./server/sandro/Sandro-PC/Printscreens/");
 $mdir = "./server/sandro/Sandro-PC/Printscreens/";
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}


closedir($myDirectory);


$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

sort($dirArray);
print("<TABLE class=table>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th></TR>\n");

for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ 
        echo('<TR><TD><a href="server/sandro/Sandro-PC/Printscreens/'.$dirArray[$index].'"><img height="80" width="120" src="server/sandro/Sandro-PC/Printscreens/'.$dirArray[$index].'"</a></td>');
        print("<td>");
        //echo(filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
        $filename = "$mdir\\$dirArray[$index]";
        echo $filename;
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
        //echo filemtime($dirArray[$index]);
        print("</td>");
        print("<td>");
       // print(filesize($dirArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}

print("</TABLE>\n");

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, works very fine. But know when I put to opan a modal in bootstrap and to show image inside the moda
i put $filename and gives the url of the last image and no the image i clickedl